# using bolt cms for single page app

Tags: bolt-cms

I want to use bolt as a headless cms. My plan is to create a template based on vue.js and load the content utilizing the bolt plugin jsonAPI.
But I'm struggling with the theme and config settings. 
I want to disable all routing in the CMS and return only a static html with css and js files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem could be solved by the following alternative solution :

**Use different domain**

Put your vue SPA app in *yourdomain.com* and put your bolt as RESTAPI provider in *subdomain.yourdomain.com*. Since it's a subdomain, you would not face any CORST problem, and you can follow common tutorial how to setup bolt cms and how to build vuejs SPA.

---

**Use vuejs SPA in bolt cms template**

Assume you develop vuejs SPA using webpack, you have to setup asset public path as bolt template location, the configuration file is in `your-vue-directory/config/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    assetsPublicPath: '/theme/your-theme/',
    ......
  },
}
```

Then after finish build the app, you can copy your build files from `your-vue-directory/dist` into `your-bolt-directory/public/theme/your-theme`

But using this solution, if you're using vue-router, i think you cannot use 'history'mode since all of the routing will be handled by bolt cms. The only possible router-mode is 'hash'.

Comment: Thank you for this great idea.
I already "solved" it by adding the css and js inline into the index.html utilizing https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin
But I did like the different domain idea and will probably change to that.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to have them all use the same template, and have that template say `<html></html>`, and you're done.